# Getting the Value from View TextBox When clicking the Send Button from Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is my view / The Modal is the one with Send(btnSend) button and I am not having luck getting
the values from hidden textbox and textbox from my mainView.

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRecipient" placeholder="Enter Lastname" />
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="txtUserID" />
                    </div>
```

This is my modal

Messages
                                        
                                            ×

```
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="msgbox"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSend">Send</button>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
```

This is my btSend Click function - My dets below is empty. I tried the getElementById as well and wasn't working either

```
$(function () {
                $("#btnSend").click(function () {
                 var x = $('#txtRecipient').val();
                  alert("btnSend" + x);

                    var dets = new Object();
                    dets.UserName = $('#txtRecipient').val();
                    dets.UserID = $('#txtUserID').val();
                    dets.MsgBox = $('#msgbox').val();
                    alert(dets);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Send/SendMessage',
                        data: JSON.stringify(dets),
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "Post",
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert(response.MsgBox);

                        },
                        error: function () {
                            //alert("something is wrong");
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                           //alert("complete");
                        }



                    });
                });
            });
```

-My function binding the data from database to txtBoxes

```
$(function () {
                $("#txtRecipient").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({

                            url: '/Send/AutoComplete',
                            data: "{ 'username': '" + request.term + "'}",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item.UserName,
                                        value: item.UserID,
                                        //+ "," + item.UserName,

                                    };
                                }))
                            },
                            error: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            },
                            failure: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    select: function (e, i) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $("#txtUserID").val(i.item.value);
                        $("#txtRecipient").val(i.item.label);


                        //alert(i.item.value);

                    },
                    minLength: 1
                }).focus(function () {
                    //$(this).autocomplete("search");
                });
            });
```

Comment: did you try  var r= $('#txtRecipient').val(); alert(r); for example?

Comment: @ Sergey Yes Sir, I did [var x = $('#txtRecipient').val();] but it is empty

Comment: I think your problem is autocomplete. I don't like url  '/Send/AutoComplete/", pls remove the last "/" and didn't check on sucess autocomplete data? Doest it bring what you need?

Comment: @Sergey Yes Sir, i did remove the extra "/" and yes, it brings backs what I need.

Comment: Did you remove the extra slash from another url? is it working now or not yet?

Comment: @Sergey Yes Sir, still not working.

Comment: Check your dats object. You can use alert(JSON.Stringify( dats)

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax urls are  not valid:

```
url: '/Send/SendMessage/',
//and
 url: '/Send/AutoComplete/',
```

you have to remove the last "/"

Comment: Sir, Thank you for the response. I edited my post with the function I used to take data from client side.